# PropertyEditor not called in ModelAttribute

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

As my title, I have problem, I can't understand why it can't. So, I have a Person class, PersonPropertyEditor class and Controller.

Here is it:

Person class:

```
public class Person {
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

PersonPropertyEditor class:

```
public class PersonPropertyEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport {
    @Override
    public void setAsText(String text) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        Person person = new Person();
        person.setName(text);

        setValue(person);
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder webDataBinder) {
        webDataBinder.registerCustomEditor(Person.class,
                new PersonPropertyEditor());
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/addPerson", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String homePost(
            @ModelAttribute("personConverted") Person personConverted) {
        System.out.println(personConverted.getName());
        return "redirect:/home";
    }
```

JSP file:

```
    <form action="addPerson" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="personConverted" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    <form>
```

So, I registered a custom property editor, and in controller, I will convert from string to person object, but I don't know why when I use ModelAttribute, Spring don't call my custom property editor, but if I use RequestParam, it's OK.

I know I can use Converter to do that, but I just want to understand why Spring don't call that, it's bug of Spring?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try using the spring form tags?

Comment: No, I didn't, because I just do it as example and I want to convert from String to Person. If I use form tags, I will use pure Person model attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with using @JsonDeserialize

```
@JsonDeserialize(using=DateTimeDeserializer.class)
public DateTime getPublishedUntil() {
    return publishedUntil;
}
```

I have to implemetd custom Deserializer.

```
public class DateTimeDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<DateTime> {

private DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(Constants.DATE_TIME_FORMAT);

public DateTimeDeserializer(){
    super(DateTime.class);
}

@Override
public DateTime deserialize(JsonParser json, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        try {
            if(StringUtils.isBlank(json.getText())){
                return null;
            }
            return formatter.parseDateTime(json.getText());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            return null;
        }
}
```

}

Comment: please explain your problem